# jquery sortable disable dragging/dropping between specific items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My situation is as follows - I'm sorting a table which may contain linked rows:

```
<table>
    <tr class="sortable-row"><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable-row"><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="linked-to-previous"><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable-row"><td>row 4</td></tr>
    <tr class="sortable-row"><td>row 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I need is to **disallow dropping the dragged row between `.linked-to-previous` and the row before it**.

I was thinking it could be done by something like this:

```
jQuery('table').sortable({
    items: '.sortable-row',
    axis: 'y',
    change: function (event, ui)
    {
        return (ui.placeholder.next('.file-version').length === 0);
    }
});
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work quite like needed - row 1 can't be dragged below row 3 because it cancels the sorting altogether.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbhykh5e/3/

Suggestions?

Comment: Something like: `onDragEnd: function() { if (this.previousSibling.hasClass("linked-to-previous") { cancelTheDrag(); } }`

Comment: @oxguy3 I don't want it to cancel he dragging, I want it to simply not place the placeholder between the two rows, and if the user drops the row there, then reset it.

Comment: How is "resetting" different from "canceling the drag event"?

Comment: @oxguy3 reset only on DROP, not drag...
Basically I want the sorting to treat those two rows as one whole row.

Comment: @jurchiks Try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `start` and `stop` method.

You can achieve both the requirements:

1. disallow dropping the dragged row between .linked-to-previous and the row before it.
2. row 1 can't be dragged below row 3 because it cancels the sorting altogether.

**Code snippets:**

```
jQuery('table').sortable({
    items: '.sortable-row',
    axis: 'y',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).data("startindex", ui.item.index());
    },
    stop: function (event, ui)
    {        
        var startIndex = ui.item.data("startindex");
        if ((startIndex < 2 && $(ui.item).prevAll('.linked-to-previous').length>0) || (startIndex > 2 && $(ui.item).nextAll('.linked-to-previous').length>0))
                $(this).sortable('cancel');        
    }    
});
```

DEMO: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbhykh5e/5/)

**UPDATE:**

**Note:**
Check your `HTML` code snippets, there you have an additional `</td>` to every rows. Please change it that to `</tr>`.

Then try the below jQuery code snippets, which meets your requirement.

```js
jQuery('table').sortable({
  items: '.sortable-row',
  axis: 'y',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).data("startindex", ui.item.index());
    $(ui.item).data("linkedindex", $(ui.item).siblings('.linked-to-previous').index());
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var startIndex = ui.item.data("startindex"),
      linkedIndex = ui.item.data("linkedindex");
    if (startIndex > linkedIndex && $(ui.item).nextAll('.linked-to-previous').length > 0)
      $(this).sortable('cancel');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="sortable-row">
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortable-row">
    <td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="linked-to-previous">
    <td>row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortable-row">
    <td>row 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortable-row">
    <td>row 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**DEMO:** [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbhykh5e/7/)

**Latest Update:**

Simply try this Code snippets

```
jQuery('table').sortable({
    items: '.sortable-row',
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).next('.linked-to-previous').length > 0)
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** [**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbhykh5e/8/)

Comment: #2 is NOT a requirement, it's an issue...
And I don't want it to cancel, I want it to treat both `.linked-to-previous` and the row before it as a single row, simply not allowing the placeholder to be put between them. That's the only requirement.

Comment: Why can't I drop rows 5 or 4 between row 1 and 2?
Also, have you considered there might be more than one `.linked-to-previous` row?

Comment: @jurchiks Now try my **Latest Update**

Comment: Sigh... No. I want it to *disallow moving the placeholder between the two rows*, just jump over them both if dragged far enough. But no cancelling.